# React: How to place Storybook .stories in each component's directory?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Currently all my `.stories` files are held within a `stories` directory. As I add more components, this will grow.

Instead I want to add each component's `.stories` file at the component level, as per the documentation on the Storybook site here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/basics/writing-stories/#loading-stories-dynamically

Thing is I don't know how to actually do this.

I have set up the following simple component (all files within same directory):

**PageTitle.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  typographyStyles: {
    flex: 1
  }
}));

interface PageTitleProps {
  title: string;
}

const PageTitle = ({ title }: PageTitleProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Typography className={classes.typographyStyles} variant="h1" component="h2">
      {title}
    </Typography>
  )
};

export default PageTitle;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import PageTitle from './PageTitle';
export default PageTitle;
```

**index.stories.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react'
import FormPageTitle from './index';

export default {
  title: 'Titles|PageTitle',
  component: PageTitle,
};

export const withText = () => {
  return <PageTitle title="Hello World" />;
};
```

In my `.storybook` directory I have a `main.js` file that simply has:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.tsx'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

But I just get the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './index' in
>   '/myApp/src/stories'

This occurs no matter what I call the .stories file.

Would anyone know the correct way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `config.js` inside your `.storybook` directory

With

```js
import React from 'react';
import { configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Decorator = (storyFn) => <Wrapper>{storyFn()}</Wrapper>;

addDecorator(Decorator);

global.___loader = {
  enqueue: () => {},
  hovering: () => {},
};

global.__PATH_PREFIX__ = '';
window.___navigate = (pathname) => {
  action('NavigateTo:')(pathname);
};

const req = require.context('../src/components/', true, /\.stories\.js$/);

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach((filename) => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```